# Compiling Tor from source

Tags: tor-install, source-code

So I compiled Tor from source using [these instructions](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#source) and everything went smoothly. However, when I look in /debian-packages/ there are three .deb files, which are:

- tor_0.4.1.6-1~d9.stretch+1_armhf.deb
- tor-dbgsym_0.4.1.6-1~d9.stretch+1_armhf.deb
- tor-geoipdb_0.4.1.6-1~d9.stretch+1_all.deb

Which of these do I use to install Tor?

Comment: First and last ones. Dbg is for debugging purpose only

Comment: Agreed and this goes for any debian/ubuntu package not just Tor.